# timezone setting in the new version of Google App Script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone, settings

Anybody knows how to change the time zone setting in the new version of Google App Script editor?

Starting with a Google App, for instance Google Docs, go to tables menu - tools - script editor - you get to Google App Script editor, where you can choose between "the old" and "the new" version.

Of course you can change to the old version, set it in file menu, still is there a shorter way?

Comment: Which software are you talking about ? What is the previous version number and the new version number ? Please provide some background.

Comment: Starting with google tables menu - tools - script editor - you get to Google App Script editor, where you can choose between "the old" and "the new" version.

Comment: You can enable "Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor" option in the Project Settings of the new Google Apps Script editor and then update the timezone in the manifest file.